# Hardhat error ProviderError: Address .... is not whitelisted

Tags: hardhat

Can't verify contract. When i run the verify task `npx hardhat verify --network goerli DEPLOYED_CONTRACT_ADDRESS 'Hello World!'`

I get

An unexpected error occurred:

ProviderError: Address 0xcBc25fC1f..... is not whitelisted

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and I was able to solve it by changing my RPC provider URL.
I was using alchemy, and even though I whitelisted the contract on Alchemy, it still wouldnt work.
I then used Infura and it just worked.
It deffinitelly seems to be a Provider issue, so if you use your own node or Infura you should be good to go.